# Subscribe to observable/subject (declared in a service)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I like to get the last value of an observable and use this in my html.
When a value is emited (next) then the html must auto update as well
The last value also must be used in a funtion as a (string) variable.

Do I have too much code for this issue or am I missing a subscibtion or something else?

**Service**

```
export class someService {
  lastUsedSubject = new BehaviourSubject<string>(null);
  lastUsed$ = this.lastUsedSubject.asObservable();
}

updateLastUsed(id: string) {
  this.lastUsedSubject.next(id);
}
```

**component** (in the onit I subscribe on a valuechange that will trigger the update some

```
@Component({
export class someComponent implements Oninit { 
      lastUsed$: Observable<string>;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formGroup.get("items").valueChanges.subscribe((val: string) => {
          this.someService.updateLastUsed(val);
        }
      }
    
      someFunction() {
        // I can use this.someService.lastUsedSubject.value to get latest value
        // service is declared in constructor
        // lastused must be a string
        somemethodcall(lastused, anotherparam);
      }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
--{{lastUsed$ | async}}--
```

Comment: Is this a missformated @Component or it looks like this since some version of anuglar?

Comment: You aren't saying how the `anotherparam` is initialized. Does the `somemethodcall()` need to stay inside the `someFunction()` function?

Comment: Not important. the somefuntion is triggered by an event/btn and the somemethod call has 2 params. one is the lastupdate as a string. it needs to be inside this function

Comment: Agreed. But `someFunction()` being a callback of a button/event is quite important. If you wish to keep things reactive, essentially you could also make the btn/click reactive (eg. using `fromEvent`) and bind the value of the `BehaviorSubject` using the `withLatestFrom` operator. In that case the subscription through the `async` and the subscription in the component controller would be two entities.

Comment: Or if you wish to do so, while still inelegant, you could use the `value` getter from the `BehaviorSubject` and use it in the btn/event's callback.

Answer (score 2):

Use `async` pipe

```
--{{lastUsed$ | async}}--
```

Comment: correct but I still not receiving the value

Comment: Try to create [mre] then

Answer (score 0):

In your template you are using `lastUsed$` from the component, though, the actual value is being updated in the service, I think you should access the Observable from the service instance, smth like:

```
@Component()
constructor(public someService: SomeService) {}
```

```
@template
{{ someService.lastUsed$ | async }}
```

Or you can init the observable in the component from the service Subject, smth like

```
@Component
lastUsed$ = this.someService.lastUsedSubject.asObservable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the get function in the service & call it from the constructor in the component. This worked for me.
Maby there is a better solution but this worked for me.

**Service**

```
export class someService {
  lastUsedSubject = new BehaviourSubject<string>(null);
  lastUsed$ = this.lastUsedSubject.asObservable();
}

getLastUsed(): Observable<string> {
  return this.lastUsed$
}

updateLastUsed(id: string) {
  this.lastUsedSubject.next(id);
}
```

**component**

```
@Component({
export class someComponent implements Oninit { 
      lastUsed$: Observable<string>;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formGroup.get("items").valueChanges.subscribe((val: string) => {
          this.someService.updateLastUsed(val);
        }
      }
      constructor(
        ...
      ) {
        this.lastUsed$ = this.someService.getLastUsed();
      }
    
      someFunction() {
        // I can use this.someService.lastUsedSubject.value to get latest value
        // service is declared in constructor
        // lastused must be a string
        somemethodcall(lastused, anotherparam);
      }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
--{{lastUsed$ | async}}--
```